# As of (date), ambiguity?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Yesterday I found out that “as of” is, especially in AmE, used often to mean “on a particular date”, not just “from a date onward”.

So I wonder:

The directive is effective as of now.

Could this be interpreted that the directive is effective just today? Intended meaning is “effective from today onwards”.

We will investigate more, but as of now, we are happy with the results.

That is the other meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of) entry, it can mean **on** or **at**. Note, though that the examples are all about things **starting on** a particular date, not just effective for the specified date, for example:

> We begin work as of Tuesday

Looking at your example:

> The directive is effective as of now.

I don't think there is any way that **now** could be taken to mean **only today**. Even if your example were

> The directive is effective as of Saturday

I don't think that this could be interpreted as **on saturday only**: it would mean effective on Saturday and from then onwards.

Comment: But “The data is correct as of Tuesday” is supposee to mean that it on Tuesday it was correct and might not be correct anymore. So I guess the context needs to be considered.

Comment: @Rpp: I would definitely interpret that to mean that there was a mistake in the data, and it was corrected on Tuesday. It is still correct, and will stay that way.

Comment: @JavaLatte Well and that would not be right, this sentence is from the Cambridge dictionary: The data is correct as of May 13. And it means "at a particular date or time". I think I have seen in it situations like this: you have data for number of passengers, which change daily. You show it to your boss and tell him - this data is valid as of May 13 (i.e the following day it likely changed)

Comment: I have also found that the Cambridge dictionary suggest "as at" in this context.